# Warning of Scala application while implementing spark Mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark

/* This is the warning am getting while running spark application using Scala IDE
I need your help to fix this warning
Here am not using Maven Project
*/

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 
    ‪C:/Datasets/creditcard.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.stringToPath(StringUtils.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:411)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(SparkContext.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(SparkContext.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:179)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at data_Classifier_package.DecisionTreeClassifier$.main(DecisionTreeClassifier.scala:46)
    at data_Classifier_package.DecisionTreeClassifier.main(DecisionTreeClassifier.scala)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: ‪C:/Datasets/creditcard.csv
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: please include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is pretty clear.

> Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 
>       `‪C:/Datasets/creditcard.csv`

Valid URI schemes are listed at https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml.

You probably want to use `file:///C:/Datasets/creditcard.csv` instead.

[File URIs in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/)

Comment: Alright I have tried probable alternatives,however  still am getting the same Exception Message.               tk421    As a remind am trying to load from local system not from cluster node